# Empty POST requests with Varnish cache

Tags: php, html, apache, varnish

So I have a very simple login-form in html/php

login1.php

```
<?php include('settings.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$basehttp;?>/login_auth1.php">
    <input name="ahd_username" type="text" id="ahd_username" size="35" maxlength="255" />
    <input name="ahd_password" type="password" id="ahd_password" size="35" maxlength="35" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

login_auth1.php

```
<?php
include('settings.php'); 
print_r($_POST);
print_r(getallheaders());

if(isset($_POST['ahd_username']) && isset($_POST['ahd_password'])){
  //database queries and stuff, send user elsewhere if login correct
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$basehttp;?>/login_auth1.php">
    <input name="ahd_username" type="text" id="ahd_username" size="35" maxlength="255" />
    <input name="ahd_password" type="password" id="ahd_password" size="35" maxlength="35" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When running login1.php (in some) web browsers the POST in login_auth1.php will be empty. But when submiting the exact same form again from login_auth1.php it works just fine. What might be the cause of this error? How to debug further? FYI The server is running [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

Link to output with headers for some calls can be found in [this textfile](http://freetexthost.com/if31oxo0fb).

**Edit:**
Have no hair left on my head now but I've figured out a way that "works". If I merge my loginfiles to a single file, put that file into a separate folder /login, removing the url in action tag completly (so it will be action="") and configure Varnish to

```
if (req.url ~ "/login"){
  set req.backend = mybackend;
  return (pass);
}
```

it will work. This feels like a really crappy "solution", especially the part with removing the string in the action tag but it's the only way that I've made it work. I've tried tons of different Varnish configurations, including  return (pipe). Does anyone have any idea on how to get it to work properly? Or why this weird version above works?

Comment: Is it possible that web crawlers like GoogleBot are visiting the `action` url without any post parameters?

Comment: `<?=$basehttp;>` I feel as though this could cause problems since you wrote `>` instead of `?>`. Maybe some browsers are parsing things correctly and others are breaking?

Comment: Firts van Campen: Yes, that is possible. But that souldn't affect my session? ಠ_ಠ: Ops, just a typo here in the forum. Not in the running code.

Comment: Don't know if that causes this problems but your form tag is not closed. Things like that usually cause browsers to act inconsistent.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Another typo - closing in running code. Pages validates.

Comment: I would guess this was a Varnish issue, do you have the same issues if you take Varnish out of the picture?

Comment: @George Unfortunately I can't just kill Varnish and test. But the same code on my local server (without Varnish) works just fine.

Comment: If you can open/access the Apache port directly you shouldn't need to kill Varnish – also, depending on the server set up, you might be able to see the traffic in the Apache/Varnish logs to help track things down.

Comment: @George Ofc! I added the apache server's ip adress to the Varnish domain name in my /etc/hosts, that sould bypass the Varnish right? If so the problem is still there...

Answer (score 0):

A good and lasting practice, to replace your quick hack, is to not cache any post requests by:

```
if ( req.request == "POST" ) {
   return (hit_for_pass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Varnish' standard behaviour[1] (at least in 3.0, debian) is to pass POST request directly to backend:

```
sub vcl_recv {
#...
  if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
    return (pass);
  }
#...
}
```

So if default code is not reached (you call return(xxx) in your vcl_recv) you should take care of this kind of requests in your own VCL code, returning a pass or either a hit_for_pass as suggested by Clarence.

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#examples